# Problem about tensor powers of operator

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

$F_1,\dots,F_m$ - linearly independent endomorphisms of vector space $V$.
I want to prove that there is no $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$(not all $\lambda_i = 0$) such for any $n > 1$
$$\lambda_1 F_1^{\otimes n}+\dots+\lambda_m F_m^{\otimes n} = 0$$

My idea is that it's not holds in $SV$ but it's give me no benefits.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general argument for tensor products of vector spaces that if $(x_i)$ are linearly independent in $X$ and $\sum_i x_i\otimes y_i = 0 \in X\otimes Y$, then all $y_i=0$.  (Apply ${\operatorname{id}_X}\otimes\varphi$ to the hypothesis, where $\varphi\in Y^\sharp$.)  It seems like you could apply that here, since we can think of the tensor product of operators $F\otimes G$ as being an element of $\operatorname{End}(V)\otimes\operatorname{End}(V)$ (which embeds in $\operatorname{End}(V\otimes V)$, where $F\otimes G$ really lives).

I'd call this a hint, but that would leave the impression that I'm deliberately withholding a complete answer for pedagogical purposes, when in fact I'm just feeling too lazy to check things carefully.